# pasting column header as axis label

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, label, paste

I have a large data frame. I would like to graph each of the columns quickly using a function. I'm having trouble getting the Y axis label to match the column header.

Here is a sample data frame.  Say I want to create two graphs with name 1 and name 2 as the y axis for each graph.

```
 dat <- data.frame(X = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
              name1 = c(50, 100, 200, 250),
              name2 = c(10, 20, 30, 40))
```

I wrote a function to create my graph

```
 plot <- function (dat, col) {
   ggplot(dat, aes(x = X, y= {{col}}, group=1))+
     geom_point(size = 1)+
     geom_line(size = 0.5)+
     theme(axis.text.y = paste0({{col}}, "plus units and other text"))
 }
```

Then I want to create my graph for column "name1"

```
 plot(dat, name1)
```

This works if I remove the theme line from my function code.  I want to Y axis to say "name1 plus units and other text."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may make use of `aes_string` and give the name1-argument as a string to function. You may also use `labs` for naming the axis title.

```
plot <- function(dat, col) {
  ggplot(dat, aes(x = X)) +
    geom_point(aes_string(y=col)) +
    geom_line(aes_string(y=col)) +
    labs(y = paste0(col, "plus units and other text"))
}
plot(dat, 'name2')
```

---

Edited after @camilles comment.
Second Option:

```
plotB <- function (dat, col) {
  colA <- enquo(col)
    ggplot(dat, aes(x = X, y= !!colA))+
      geom_point(size = 1)+
      geom_line(size = 0.5) +
      ylab(paste(quo_name(colA), ' Units'))
}

plotB(dat, name2)
```

Comment: Just FYI `aes_string` has been soft-deprecated for a bit now in favor of tidyeval

Comment: @camille, thank your for the hint. Indeed I am (a bit behind), but I have edited my answer and did not use deprecated `aes_string`.

Comment: Great suggestion!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a variable for `col`, then inside the function, you can do substitute() to capture the expression for `col`, and note it should be ylab instead of theme(..) for changing the y label:

```
    plot <- function (dat, col) {
   ggplot(dat, aes(x = X, y= {{col}}, group=1))+
     geom_point(size = 1)+
     geom_line(size = 0.5)+
     ylab(substitute(col))
     #ylab()
 }
```

If you need to append a more complicated expression to your ylab, do something like:

```
plot <- function (dat, col) {
   LAB=substitute(V:Ca ~ (µmol ~ mol^{-1}) , list(V = substitute(col)))
   ggplot(dat, aes(x = X, y= {{col}}, group=1))+
     geom_point(size = 1)+
     geom_line(size = 0.5)+
     ylab(LAB)
 }
```

Do check out [this chapter on quasiquotations](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html) to better use them.

Comment: Thank you!  That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: What about if I want my axis label to include an expression (ie. mol-1).  In the past I have used 
     labs(x = NULL, y = expression("V:Ca" ~ (µmol ~ mol^{-1})))

where V is the column name I want.
 
Why doesn't this work: 
 ylab(paste(enexpr(col), expression(":Ca" ~ (µmol ~ mol^{-1}))))

Comment: it doesn't work because one is a character, the other is an expression. It is possible to do it.. but isn't it making your code more complicated than need be?

Comment: @KimberlyPeter, try the updated solution.. it should work, but.. i really don't know if it is a good function to use